# Multiple URL rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can`t understand, why URL rewrite doesn`t work.

I have script, who get files with content.

```
   if($pg){
        if(file_exists("resources/pages/".$pg.".php")){
            include("resources/pages/".$pg.".php");
        }
        else{
            include("resources/pages/notfound.php");
        }
   }
   else {
        include("resources/pages/home.php");
   }
```

And htaccess, who need to rewrite URLs. There are categories, pages, and language strings needs to rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?pg=$1 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1&pg=$2 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1&pg=$2 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1&cat=$2 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1&cat=$2&pg=$3 [NC,L]
```

This displays internal server error. If I leave only first row with

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [L]
```

only language switch work ok. When put second row

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?lang=$1 [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?cat=$1 [NC,L]
```

language switch work, but next rules doesn`t work. :(

Answer (score 0):

The `OR` flag is only used in a `RewriteCond`, it'll give you an error if you attempt to use it with a `RewriteRule`. The problem you have is that URIs that get routed to `/?lang=`, `/?cat=`, and `/?pg=` are *identical* as far as the matching pattern is concerned. Given this url:

```
http://yourdomain.com/blahblah/
```

All 3 of your patterns (which are all `^([^/]*)/$`) matches `/blahblah/` and groups `blahblah` as a backrefernce using **$1**. But is it a lang? Is it a cat? Or is it a page?. You'll need to uniquely create patterns to match each of the 3 and they have to be mutually exclusive.

Is the `pg` parameter only numbers? If so, then the pattern that routes to it should be `^([0-9]+)/$`. Is the lang variable only 2 letters? If so, then the pattern that routes to lang should be `^([a-z]{2})/$`. Note that this would only work if the cat parameter *is either 1 character or more than 2, or contains numbers and symbols*.

Whatever it is, you'll need to work it out. That's why you're seeing this behavior.